# iOS : UINavigationbar overlapping with Statusbar for 6 plus device only

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, statusbar

how to solve the the UINavigationbar overlapping  with Statusbar for 6 plus device only for menu based app?

```
-(void) openpane
{
    self.pushBehaviour.pushDirection = CGVectorMake(35.0f, 0.0f);
    self.gravityBehaviour.gravityDirection = CGVectorMake(GRAVITY_FORCE,0.0f);
    self.pushBehaviour.active = YES;
    self.isMenuOpen = YES;
}
-(void) closePane
{
    self.pushBehaviour.pushDirection = CGVectorMake(-35.0f, 0.0f);
    self.gravityBehaviour.gravityDirection = CGVectorMake(-GRAVITY_FORCE,0.0f);
    self.pushBehaviour.active = YES;
    self.isMenuOpen = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the constraint constant 20 from the top for navigation bar.

Comment: i have added navigationbar programatically

Comment: then you can try to make its translucent property to false